# View call to another view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have created a popup view(EmployeeRegistration.cshtml) using Bootstrap for registration and its Action method. But I want to get this popup view from another view(EmployeeList.cshtml). Can I do it? If yes then How? Any code please.
//EmployeeList.cshtml

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Registration", "Registration", new
{
    @class = "openDialog",
    data_dialog_id = "aboutDialog",
    data_dialog_title = "Create Employee"
})

<div id="gridposition" style="width: 100%;">
    @{

        @grid1.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
//code to display employee list on grid
     }
</div>
```

Below is Registration.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="modal fade mymodal" id="openDialogDiv">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

//code here to pop up
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to show popup on click of ActionList as shown above

Comment: Not sure if I'm following this completely but why does this have to be an ActionLink? Dont you want just an onclick event for the modal popup to appear?

Comment: yup, on click of ActionLink a Popup View will open with Registration form

Comment: when you click on href link, you need to show the popup right? what about the url? it should remain the same or what?

Answer (score 0):

Create a a div in your EmployeeList.cshtml to hold the html returned from Registration.cshtml

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Make your Registration.cshtml as a partial view.

Use this anchor tag.

```
 <a href ="#" onclick="funName()" class=="openDialog">Create New </a>
```

Make an ajax request to get the popup content and onsuccess, populate the div with the returned html and open the modal popup.

```
<script>
function funName()
{
   $.ajax({
   url: 'yoururl',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(data) {
               $('#info').html(data);
               $('#mymodal').modal('show');
              },
   error: function() {}
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think There are two options :
1. Forget about `Registration.cshtml` and put the below code in EmployeeList.cshtml:

```
  <button type="button" class="openDialog">Create New</button>
  <form class="modal fade mymodal" id="openDialogDiv" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
             //code here to pop up
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

then show the form using jquery:

```
$('.openDialog').click(function(){
   $('#openDialogDiv').modal();
});
```

2.create new action method in your controller which returns `EmployeeRegistration.cshtml` as partial view, let me name it `DisplayRegistration()` , now you can use ajax call, to `DisplayRegistration()` and display `EmployeeRegistration.cshtml`.
Please note that I changed `Html.ActionLink` to `<button>` tag